# String.hashcode() Clarification

Tags: java, string, hash, hashcode

I was looking at the `String.hashcode()` function.
It's defined as:

This method returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as:

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

Using int arithmetic, where `s[i]` is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

The question here is `s[0]` refers to the 0th character or rather the nth character in the string. But is it the int value of that character that is used to compute the hashcode?

Comment: `is it the int value of that character that is used to compute the hashcode?` Answer is YES.

Answer (score 2):

Every char has a numeric value (ASCII/ UTF-16/ etc...). That is being use in this calculation
e.g.

```
char x = 'A';
System.out.println(x * 2); // output is 130
```

that is because numeric value of 'A' is 65

Comment: Actually, it's not ASCII, but UTF-16 encoding of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest type Java execute arithmetic operations on is int. So `s[0]*31^(n-1)` is converted to `((int)s[0])*31^(n-1)`